# How to get first login and last logout from multiple login and logout for one single date?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table called daily_data which has data about the employee's login and logout. Now there are multiple entries for login and logout. So i just want to fetch the first login and the last logout for each day. How do i do that i codeigniter?

If the entry for login/logout is greater than 100 its login otherwise its a logout. This is a bio-metric data.

This is my controller:

```
    public function index()
    {

    $this->data['attendances'] = $this->attendance_m->join_data();

    $this->data['attendance_dropdown'] = $this->attendance_m->get_emp_list();



    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/attendance/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

The Model:

```
public function join_data()
  {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('daily_data2', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();


    $res   = $query->result();        
      return $res;
  }
```

The Daily_Data Table:

[image: dailydata]

Comment: I think you may use an additional field in table for indicating first login and last logout, and make that field default. For each day, you just reset the first login and last login field. Using that field you can fetch the data in the `join_data` function.

Comment: but i have multiple data entries how to identify the first login  and last logout @Astro

Comment: do u have field for date at your daily_data2 table? @Rajan

Comment: Yes i have field called date in which i have data and time

Comment: ok then you may use your date for checking whether it is a first log and last logout.. i.e, during the updation of your daily_data2 table, you just check whether the date already exists or not, if not then the record will be the first login. so just add an field for indication and set that record value as 1 remaining change as 0. the record which has the value 1 are the first login for the date

Comment: @Astro  for single date employee has multiple login and logout! how to find which one is the first and last

Comment: yes, date is same for all employee for single day ?

Comment: See for eg for today's date i may have more than one logins and logouts so for each day i want to find when firstly he loggedin and when was his last logout for that particular day @Astro

Comment: can u post your daily_data2 table insert function

Comment: i have posted the table @Astro

Comment: so the table will updated for each time of login and logout? @Rajan

Comment: No Biometric give output file i upload and import that data into mysql table

Comment: oh k.. then for date fetch all the login and logout details of a person. and after that you have to loop through the records for finding out the first login. And it is a sound logic you should work on further  @Rajan

Comment: That's my actual probelm @Astro i dont knw what should be the logic for getting only the first login and last logout

Comment: @Astro Can you give me the logic to find the first and last login details

Comment: i think u may use `$this->db->query('Select * from users,daily_data2 where daily_data2.date_data like 24-12-2015' AND users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id)` this to get the records of an employer, after that using foreach compare the date time

Comment: @Astro do u know how to limit the data by one ? i am thinking this db select where date="somedate" and limit by 1 can u tell me what should be my query to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98890/discussion-between-astro-and-rajan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting first entry of the login for the particular date, use this query `SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE date_data2 like "2015-11-04" LIMIT 1`

Model,

```
public function testing() 
{ 
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE date_data2 like "2015-11-04" LIMIT 1'); 
return $query; 
}
```